# Software for categorizing data based on language and type

Tags: microsoft-excel, data, search

Currently, I'm using windows file explorer for categorizing. There are folders for years (2017, 2018, etc.) and each of them has sub-folders for types (type_1, type_2, etc.) and under each sub-folder, I have an Excel file where I can add, delete, update or search data. Is there any software where I can store all my data in one place, categorize them and do CRUD operations?